# image full width - one works, other not?

Tags: flutter, image, dart, width

i'm trying to give 2 imagines (they're the same image) full width for the app i'm working on (it gotta be responsive tho) but not full length, this should be pretty easy, i know. but weird thing is in one page it works while the other not, while they're the exact same code, except one (content-related) has a `container` with `gradientlinear`. i don't think this is the issue but i have no idea what would be otherwise.

i have tried many things (e.g. changing width, removing `fit: BoxFit.contain`, heck even tried to change the `aspectRatio` & added my own width and length instead of `BoxFit.contain`, and the whole `AspectRatio`) but nothing works. i already also have tried to restart my debugging service (chrome) and tried ctrl+shift+r (i was thinking maybe cache) but nothing.

please someone help, i don't understand why it's not working and i feel like i'm going insane bcs of such a small thing.

i even provided the screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf2fJ.png), as you can see the right one has a bit more space..

**This is the first code (the working one):**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:test_niyata_flutter/login/login_second.dart';

class Login1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Login1({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 20),

                // Logo image
                Image.asset(
                  '../assets/Images/Logo.png',
                  width: 126,
                  height: 38,
                ),

                // Login1 image
                Flexible(
                  fit: FlexFit.tight,
                  child: AspectRatio(
                    // 375 is the width of the image and 462.88 is the height of the image. This makes it scalable
                    aspectRatio: 375 / 462.88,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      '../assets/Images/Login1.png',
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                Column(
                  children: [
                    // Text
                    const Text(
                      "Text here",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        fontSize: 17,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 15),
                    const Text(
                      """Another long  
text here!""",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                        fontSize: 14,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),

                    // Buttons
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 45,
                      width: 223,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => const Login2(),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          backgroundColor: const Color(0xffB9F5AA),
                        ),
                        child: const Text(
                          "Let's go!",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 17,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 45,
                      width: 223,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  const Login2(), // HIER MOET NOG NAAR GEKEKEN WORDEN
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        child: const Text(
                          'Button',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 17,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 15),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**and this is the other one, which doesn't work:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Login2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login2({super.key});

  @override
  State<Login2> createState() => _Login2State();
}

class _Login2State extends State<Login2> {
  bool _obscureText = true;
  String _emailError = ''; // Error message for email validation
  String _passwordError = ''; // Error message for password validation
  static const _emailRegex = r'^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$';

  void _togglePasswordVisibility() {
    setState(() {
      _obscureText = !_obscureText;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 20),

                // Logo image
                Image.asset(
                  '../assets/Images/Logo.png',
                  width: 126,
                  height: 38,
                ),

                // Login1 image
                Flexible(
                  fit: FlexFit.tight,
                  child: AspectRatio(
                    // 375 is the width of the image and 462.88 is the height of the image. This makes it scalable
                    aspectRatio: 375 / 462.88,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      '../assets/Images/Login1.png',
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          colors: [
                            Color.fromARGB(255, 185, 245, 170),
                            Colors.white,
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          // This is to make the text and the underline stack with each other
                          Stack(
                            children: [
                              Positioned(
                                bottom: 2,
                                left: 0,
                                right: 0,
                                child: Container(
                                  height: 1.0,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                ),
                              ),

                              // Text underline
                              Text(
                                "",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    inherit: false,
                                    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                    fontSize: 17,
                                    foreground: Paint()
                                      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
                                      ..strokeWidth = 2),
                              ),

                              // Text with color
                              const Text(
                                "Inloggen",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  inherit: false,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                  fontSize: 17,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),

                          const SizedBox(height: 10),

                          // "Email" textfield
                          TextField(
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                              fontSize: 17,
                              color: Color(0xFF8FA0B4),
                            ),
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                final emailRegExp = RegExp(_emailRegex);
                                if (value.isEmpty) {
                                  _emailError =
                                      'Vul alstublieft uw e-mailadres in.';
                                } else if (!emailRegExp.hasMatch(value)) {
                                  _emailError =
                                      'Voer een geldig e-mailadres in.';
                                } else {
                                  _emailError =
                                      'Vul alstublieft uw e-mailadres in.';
                                }
                              });
                            },
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              enabled: true,
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                              ),
                              contentPadding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                              labelText: 'Email',
                              errorText: _emailError,
                            ),
                          ),

                          // "Wachtwoord" textfield
                          TextField(
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                              fontSize: 17,
                              color: Color(0xFF8FA0B4),
                            ),
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                if (value.isEmpty) {
                                  _passwordError =
                                      'Vul alstublieft uw wachtwoord in.';
                                } else {
                                  _passwordError =
                                      'Vul alstublieft uw wachtwoord in.';
                                }
                              });
                            },
                            obscureText: _obscureText,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              enabled: true,
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                              ),
                              contentPadding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                              labelText: 'Wachtwoord',
                              errorText: _passwordError,
                              suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: _togglePasswordVisibility,
                                child: Icon(
                                  _obscureText
                                      ? Icons.visibility
                                      : Icons.visibility_off,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),

                          const SizedBox(height: 10),

                          // Buttons
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 45,
                            width: 223,
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => const Login2(),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                backgroundColor: const Color(0xffB9F5AA),
                              ),
                              child: const Text(
                                'Inloggen',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 17,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 15),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: From what I see in the screenshots, the two images have different space available due to the different height of the bottom widget

Comment: which bottom widget? do you mean the SizedBox at the very end of the code or do you mean the piece that starts with Colum -> children: -> Container -> BoxDecoration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Dhafin Rayhan in the comments, if there is insufficient vertical space available, the aspect ratio is maintained, but the whole image is scaled down.

### Solution 1

Instead, you can try to use a different `BoxFit` for your image. If you use `BoxFit.fitWidth`, it should take up all available horizontal space, but this cuts off part of the top and bottom of the image if insufficient space is available. Using `BoxFit.cover` will make it fit both horizontally as well as vertically, but changes the aspect ratio...

```dart
Image.asset(
  '../assets/Images/Login1.png',
  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
),
```

### Solution 2

Another alternative is to put the whole view in a `SingleChildScrollView`, which should allow the image to expand to its full size, but you'll have to scroll if the content does not fit on the device, which may result in a button not being visible. Not really a solution either.

### Testing the issue

To test/verify if the lack of vertical space is indeed what's causing the issue: Try to replace your image with one that has a different aspect ratio, say 16:9. This should fit the full width in both of your example snippets, and have some vertical space left. Or you could test it by removing the email field, see if that makes the image expand to the full width again.

Comment: I'll use and see what solution 1 does. Also, about solution2, i try to avoid using SingleChildScrollView, for the homepage we try to make it as clean as possible without having the user to scroll, so that explains that. Thank you!

Comment: Solution 1 worked for me apparently. but not only that, i had to also add "width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width," otherwise i'd keep a little space. Thanks once again!